# Mongodb agregation on computed sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am working on photo sharing application that has a mongodb model that looks a bit like:

```
    Location = { _id : id, address : address, name : name } 

    Photo = { 
         _id: id, 
         _upvotes : [{ ref to User }], 
         _location : {ref to Location}, 
         url: url, 
         selected : boolean 
 }
```

A quick overview of the code that I want to modify (nodejs/expressjs/mongoose):

```
Photo.find({})
     .populate('_location')
     .stream({ objectMode : true })
     .pipe(res);//res being response stream in express.js
```

Is there a way to query on Photo model in such a way that:

```
If there is no Photo.selected in a Location
Then find the photo with maximum votes, by counting the length of upvotes
```

I did a deep research using MongoDBs mapReduce implementation, agregation framework, and $where operator, but did not find my way out.

If there is any other question, or reference that may lead to an answer, or a specific approach to follow, please let me know.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a referenced schema. MapReduce and aggregate operate on single collections only, just like the rest of MongoDB. Populate does not "join" it just emulates it by doing multiple queries. If you need to aggregate like this you need to embed, or do all your aggregating in the client.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your input, do you have a pseudo-code/code I can follow? there should be no calculations on client, as this is an API actually, the response should be ready to use. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: By "client" I mean your node application as it is a client to MongoDB. You would at the very least need to "embed" the location data in your "photo" document rather than use a referenced schema. Is this what you are asking? As for how to code this differently, you need to provide more of an explanation of your logic and results. Your current code should do if what you are looking for is transfer to MongoDB for processing.